# Правильно ли построено предложение и поставлена запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, выбор-слов

Правильно ли?

> Вы забыли пароль?
>
> Укажите свою эл. почту, и мы отправим туда ваш пароль

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со знаками всё правильно, запятая разделяет две составляющих сложносочиненного предложения.
Однако сокращения тут лучше не использовать. Понимаю, что без сокращения длинно получается, но все равно лучше писать полностью. Если совсем места нет, то "Укажите адрес почты" "Укажите свой E-mail" и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!